# Error that font=('Courier', 24, 'normal') are also values for the argument align='center'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
pen.write('Player A:', str(score_a),  'Player B:', str(score_b), align='center', font=('Courier', 24, 'normal'))
```

(turtle imported)
(score_a and score_b are variables that contain a boolean)
This happened right after I added str(score_a) and str(score_b). Why is it like that and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that turtle `write()` works like Python `print()`, it doesn't.  It only takes one thing to write, not multiple.  You can try:

```
pen.write('Player A: ' + str(score_a) + ' Player B: ' + str(score_b), align='center', font=('Courier', 24, 'normal'))
```

or:

```
pen.write('Player A: {}  Player B: {}'.format(score_a, score_b), align='center', font=('Courier', 24, 'normal'))
```

Or whatever approach you prefer to generate a single item to write.